# Как сделать, чтобы при сжатии background уменьшался, занимая всю ширину экрана?

Tags: html, css

[image: Вот как выглядит при уменьшение ширины]
Вариант с

```
wrapper { 
  overflow: hidden; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

не подходит, через невозможность адекватного использования гридов...

Comment: Попробуйте Единицы измерения vh, vw, vmin, vmax

Comment: а ваш код можно?

Comment: вот так выглядит мой background .header__fon {
  background-image: url(/img/header/header.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    background: url('/images/image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: background-size: не решает проблемы